# Inspect widget font, margin, padding and other properties

Tags: flutter, properties, inspector, flutter-desktop

Using flutter inspector I'm not able to find a list of widget's properties like font size, font family, border color, padding, margin ...
For example, in a `Text` widget the available properties are `textDirection`, `textAlign`, `size`, and a few more, like in screenshot below:

[image: dart dev tools screenshot]

I would like to see all computed properties, like browsers do:

[image: browser inspector screenshot]

Of course they are different tools, but i would like to know if there is a way to check more properties.

I also found a code-based solution, to access widget properties after it has been rendered, like in this question:
[How to get the TextFormField text color,fontsize, etc using controller in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541416/how-to-get-the-textformfield-text-color-fontsize-etc-using-controller-in-flutte)

Is that the best way to achieve the result? Is it possible to use `Key`s in a way which allows to access widget properties without using a custom widget (i would like to save the reference to a `Text`, `Row`, etc. widgets and print all their properties)?

I also tried to use `toDiagnosticsNode` and `toStringDeep` methods as follows (`_textWidget` is of course a `Text` widget created above, this code is called when i click a button):

```
var test = _textWidget.toDiagnosticsNode().getProperties();

if (test != null && test.isNotEmpty) {
  test.forEach((element) {
    print(element.toStringDeep());
  });
}
```

Is it possible to play a bit with a recursive function to get all the properties? All i can see with that code is the text displayed.